# Divergence (unevenness) in provisions of favours of Allah (health, wealth, phisical abilities, prosperity) among humans. [6:165; 43:32; 16:71]

Tags: tafseer

I came accross sura 6:165, where Allah (SWT) says following:

"And it is He who has made you successors upon the earth and **has raised some of you above others in degrees [of rank]** that He may try you through what He has given you. Indeed, your Lord is swift in penalty; but indeed, He is Forgiving and Merciful. (Al-An'am 6:165 / Sahih International)

I was particularly interested in the reason for raising some above others. While trying to find the answer, I also came accross 16:71, 43:32 and 4:32 - which also speak about "different levels" being gransted to different people.

In essense, I understand this is about testing people - Allah (SWT) gives to some more and less to others (be it health, wealth, etc); he tests and wants to see how would people deal with the wealth given and expects humans to distribute the wealth and follow the guidance related to charity, giving and supporting others provided in Quran.

However, what I dont understand is why has Allah (SWT) chosen such a way to test people, since in a such an approach, inevitably some become poor and some become rich, some suffer while others prosper. I wonder if there is any explanation to this by any of the scholars or researchers?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

السلام عليكم و رحمة الله و بركاته

Answer is here, Allah says in Surah ash-shuraa in verse 27:

> And if Allâh were to enlarge the provision for His slaves, they would
> surely **rebel in the earth**, but He sends down by **measure** as He wills.

To explain further:

Firstly, we need to accept that our intelligence is inferior to Allah's knowledge and wisdom. Our intelligence is limited and there are certain things we cannot comprehend.

> No vision can comprehend Him, and He comprehends all visions, and He
> is Absolutely Subtle, All-Aware. Quran 6:103

Secondly, we are not the creator of this eco-system(Creation). Hence the Creator alone knows how to design the eco-system to be functional. Hence it is from the wisdom of the creator to send things in measure and raise some of you above others.

> “And it may be that you dislike a thing which is good for you and that
> you like a thing which is bad for you. Allah knows but you do not
> know.” (AI-Baqarah, 2:216)

Comment: Many thanks this is very helpfull!